# How to access JSON from external data source in Terraform?

Tags: ruby, terraform

I am receiving JSON from a `http` terraform data source

```
data "http" "example" {
  url = "${var.cloudwatch_endpoint}/api/v0/components"

  # Optional request headers
  request_headers {
    "Accept" = "application/json"
    "X-Api-Key" = "${var.api_key}"
  }
}
```

It outputs the following.

```
http = [{"componentID":"k8QEbeuHdDnU","name":"Jenkins","description":"","status":"Partial Outage","order":1553796836},{"componentID":"ui","name":"ui","description":"","status":"Operational","order":1554483781},{"componentID":"auth","name":"auth","description":"","status":"Operational","order":1554483781},{"componentID":"elig","name":"elig","description":"","status":"Operational","order":1554483781},{"componentID":"kong","name":"kong","description":"","status":"Operational","order":1554483781}]
```

which is a string in terraform. In order to convert this string into JSON I pass it to an `external` data source which is a simple ruby function. Here is the terraform to pass it.

```
data "external" "component_ids" {
  program = ["ruby", "./fetchComponent.rb",]

  query = {
    data = "${data.http.example.body}"

  }
}
```

Here is the ruby function

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'json'
data = JSON.parse(STDIN.read)
results = data.to_json
STDOUT.write results
```

All of this works. The `external` data outputs the following (It appears the same as the `http` output) but according to terraform docs this should be a `map`

```
external1 = {
  data = [{"componentID":"k8QEbeuHdDnU","name":"Jenkins","description":"","status":"Partial Outage","order":1553796836},{"componentID":"ui","name":"ui","description":"","status":"Operational","order":1554483781},{"componentID":"auth","name":"auth","description":"","status":"Operational","order":1554483781},{"componentID":"elig","name":"elig","description":"","status":"Operational","order":1554483781},{"componentID":"kong","name":"kong","description":"","status":"Operational","order":1554483781}]
}
```

I was expecting that I could now access data inside of the `external` data source. I am unable.

Ultimately what I want to do is create a `list` of the `componentID` variables which are located within the `external` data source.

Some things I have tried

```
* output.external: key "0" does not exist in map data.external.component_ids.result in:

${data.external.component_ids.result[0]}
```

```
* output.external: At column 3, line 1: element: argument 1 should be type list, got type string in:

${element(data.external.component_ids.result["componentID"],0)}
```

```
* output.external: key "componentID" does not exist in map data.external.component_ids.result in:

${data.external.component_ids.result["componentID"]}
```

```
ternal: lookup: lookup failed to find 'componentID' in:

${lookup(data.external.component_ids.*.result[0], "componentID")}
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: It probably is a map, but with only one kv pair where the value is the entire string output from the external data. The problem is likely the Ruby script output formatting.

Answer (score 0):

can't test with the variable `cloudwatch_endpoint`, so I have to think about  the solution.

Terraform can't decode json directly before 0.11.x. But there is a workaround to work on nested lists.

Your ruby need be adjusted to make output as variable `http` below, then you should be fine to get what you need.

```
$ cat main.tf 
variable "http" {
  type = "list"
  default = [{componentID = "k8QEbeuHdDnU", name = "Jenkins"}]
}

output "http" {
  value = "${lookup(var.http[0], "componentID")}"
}

$ terraform apply 

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

http = k8QEbeuHdDnU
```